# IE 8 doesn't scroll to #id of <tr>

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

When using long table and each row `<tr>` is having its id, [IE 8 will not scroll to that row (see test link)](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/pub/bugs/ie-doesnt_scroll_to_id_of_tr/test.html#user_20) when using `#id` in the URL. It works in FF.

- why so? Is IE buggy (I guess so) or it's just a grace of FF?
- any workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me, have you ensured the correct case of the letters & spelling? Also make sure the same id hasn't been used more than once, that might confuse it.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, please look at the link I added to my post. Doesn't work for me. Of course no id is used twice.

Comment: Works for me as well, in IE8, including the link that was posted.

Comment: The test link worked fine for me as well. I can only suggest clearing the cache on your browser, uploading to another location and test it there, or test it on another IE8 (alternate PC or laptop) and see if you get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: it works if the id is placed to the `<td>` element.

Answer (score -1):

you can use name attribute with id.

and yeah Internet Explorer sucks. 
I suggest you use either FF or Chrome.

Comment: are you joking? My role is a web developer, not user. You could have guessed it because StackOverflow is site for software developers, not for users :-) I perfectly agree with you, however.

Comment: Except this works correctly in two different users instances of IE8, and your answer is not an answer.

Comment: yeah thanks for your thumb down but it doesn't change anything and ah I know there are everywhere Microsoft fans. more likely errand boys.
what I made was a suggestion and which also can be considered as an answer.